# How to disable "overwrite mode" in the cmd when it is opened from Notepad++?

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++

I am struggeling with this issue. Everytime when I open my cmd with windows I can write the following:
[image]

And then correct it, by moving to the space before you:

[image]

But when I open it with notepad++, which seems to be opened with `cmd /K cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)`
I try the same:

[image]

And when I shift the coursor and start typing:

[image]

Everything which is at the right gets overwritten. I have to always click the `Insert` key to disable this functionality. This is quiet annoying, but I can not find the reason for this. If I execute the same command form the cmd it works without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command Windows remember the state for launch of same name. Launch CMD from Notepad++ once more, use left mouse on the top left icon of CMD Windows and select `Properties` then tickbox by Insert Mode. It should remember the setting for next launch

Answer (score 0):

It is set in registry under HKCU\Console\ InsertMode=1

I think the trick is to open cmd loose (ie from the start menu), and operate its settings from there.  Go to alt-space\Poperties\options, and insertmode is on the right.

Quickedit allows you to select text with the mouse without going through the menu.  It stops the mouse clicks going to the app, though.